# Time of Strings Creation in Java

Tags: java, string

I am writing an app for J2ME devices and pretty much care about unnecessary String creation.
As working with Strings is built-in, i.e. it is not necessary to create them explicitly, I am not sure if I understand it right.

For instance returning a String (just by using the double quotes) creates the string when it is being returned, i.e. if I have several return statements returning different Strings, only one of the would be created. Is that right?

Also when using Strings for printing messages with Exceptions, these Strings never get created, if the Exception doesn't get thrown, right?

Sorry to bother you with such a newbie question.

Comment: Thanks all very much for all the bother!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not at all sure about the answers you've received so far. If you're *just* returning a string literal, e.g.

```
return "foo";
```

then those values are embedded into the class file. The JVM makes sure that only one instance of that string is ever created (from the literal) - but I don't think there's any guarantee that it won't create strings for *all* the constants in a class when the class itself is loaded.

Then again, because the string will only be created *once* (per string constant) it's unlikely to be an issue.

Now, if your code is actually more like this:

```
return "foo" + new Date();
```

then that *is* dynamically creating a string - but it will only be created if the return statement is actually hit.

Comment: It says at `String#intern': *All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned.*. So a String, that is based on a literal is created once and at least when the first expression using that literal is executed. I doubt that the classloader will look at the constant pool and create String instances for all literals proactivly. But you never know ;)

Comment: @Andreas_D: It would make life a lot easier if it did, I'd say.

Comment: Thanks Jon! You're always very practical and helpful!

Comment: Andreas, would you explain to me what you mean by saying "I doubt that the classloader will look at the constant pool and create String instances for all literals proactivly."?

Comment: @Jon - Just looked at the [JVM spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#19124), and to my surprise and your reassurance: *Loading of a class or interface that contains a String literal may create a new String object (§2.4.8) to represent that literal. This may not occur if the a String object has already been created [...]*

Comment: If I've interpreted it correctly, [the specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#22972) suggests that the class' constant pool (and by association the string literals) is created when the class is created by the class loader, so I imagine this would typically result in the majority of said strings being created during startup? I may be way off base with that conclusion, though.

Comment: @Tim - it is my understanding that it does create the Strings at class load time.  However, it possible that JVM / classloader avoid creating String objects for Strings that are already in the string pool ... unlike what has to happen when you call `String.intern()` from application code.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a bit more complicated than some of the other answers suggest.

- The String value that corresponds to a String literal in your source code gets created once, when the class is loaded.  Furthermore, *these* Strings are automatically "interned", which means that if the same literal appears at more than one place *in any class*, only one copy of the String will be kept.  (Any other copies, *if they were created* will get garbage collected.)
- When the application calls `new String(...)`, when it evaluates a String concatenation expression (i.e. the `+` operator), or when it calls one of the many library methods that create Strings under the hood, a new String will be created.

So to answer your questions:

1 - The following will not actually create a String at all.  Rather it will return a String that was created when the class was loaded:

```
        return "some string";
```

2 - The following will create two Strings.  First it will call someObject.toString(), then it will concatenate that with the literal to give another String.

```
        return "The answer is :" + someObject;
```

3 - The following will not create a String; see 1.

```
        throw new Exception("Some message");
```

4 - The following will create two Strings when it is executed; see 2.

```
        throw new Exception(someObject + "is wrong");
```

(Actually, 3 and 4 gloss over the fact that creating an exception causes details of the current thread's call stack to be captured, and those details include a method name, class name and file name for each frame.  It is not specified when the Strings that represent these things actually get created, or whether they are interned.  So *it is possible* that the act of creating an Exception object triggers creation of a number of Strings.)

Comment: Are you actually sure of 1? I mean, the others seem to be saying that returning a String literal was the same as invoking the constructor on a String object, with the difference that it was automatically pooled, so why should it be created at class-loading time?

Comment: @Albus - I am **sure** of this.  This also agrees with what @Jon Skeet says ... so it must be right :-)

Comment: I second Stephen's conclusion (and faith in Jon Skeet). :P

Answer (score 1):

1. Right
2. Right

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Yes. If an expression that creates an instance either by invoking a constructor or if (for Strings) evaluating a literal is not executed, then nothing is created.</strike>

<strike>And furtheron, compilers do some optimization. String objects based on String literals will be created only once and interned afterwards. like here:</strike>

```
public String getHello() {
  return "Hello";  
}

public void test() {
  String s = getHello();  // String object created
  String t = getHello();  // no new String object created
}
```

---

The [JVMS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#19124) has a different 'opinion':

> A new class instance may be implicitly created in the following situations:
>
> - Loading of a class or interface that contains a String literal may create a new String object (§2.4.8) to represent that literal. This may not occur if the a String object has already been created to represent a previous occurrence of that literal, or if the String.intern method has been invoked on a String object representing the same string as the literal.

So the above example is incorrect (I'm learning something new every day). The VM checks during classloading if `"Hello"` has to be created or not (and will create a String instance if not existing yet).

So now it is my understanding, that the VM creates a String instance for each unique String literal (on byte code level!), regardless whether it is used or not.

(*on byte code level* because compilers may optimize concatenations of String literals to one literal, like: the expression `"one"+"two"` will be compiled to `"onetwo"`)

Comment: I begin to suspect that all Strings are interned unless _specially_ declared that are not. So it seems that creating a String instance by a String literal is the same as creating an object, implementing the Flyweight pattern.

Comment: @Albus - Well, it's important not to fall into traps, though. Java interning is done with compile-time guarantees in mind, so iterative string creation *based* on literals (e.g. imaginary method `repeat("*", 5)`) doesn't gain any benefit from automatic interning (which you probably know now). It's more of a best-efforts operation on the part of the JVM, using the available up-front information. On a side note, thanks for the interesting question, it made me consider something I want to go experiment with now.

Answer (score 0):

Strings (and other objects) only get created when you call them.

So to answer your questions:

1. Yes, only the String that gets returned will get created
2. Yes, only when the exception is thrown, this String will get created

Answer (score 0):

The main concept here is that the heap allocation(what you say creation) for any String or in more general terms for any object doesn't take place until your logic-flow makes the interpreter executes that line of compiled code.